# Why do My flying baloon freezes some frames when flying through the map after I clicked into "Tips window"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, game-development, freeze

I'm developing a game for a geography interactive lesson for initial years.

the student will fly with a balloon (that is a gif ), through a big map (also  and gif).

there are many buttons (also img tags with .png this time), and I have a compass calculating its location while flying (that I also hardly believe that i'm calculating it wrong)...

But my highest problem is: After some seconds flying through the map, if I click on "Tips" ("Dicas" in portuguese) and press the "next" button to the next tip, and then I close it to go back and flying along the map, some frames are lost...

I don't know how I can optimize that, I have seen so many giant codes running javascript, css and html games compared to this of mine, I don't know  how I can calculate the memory used... (sorry by my ignorance, i'm still learning)...

Thank you for the future answer that will help my problem!! Eternal Gratitude!!!

Ah here is the repository, and the deploy link:

repository: https://github.com/luis-mendes-95/game-pelo-mundo

deploy link: https://luis-mendes-95.github.io/game-pelo-mundo/

Tried starting html elements sometimes inside the javascript file, other times structured inside html file...

And also I changed the frames configuration for less calculations (ignorantly, because chatGPT made that block of code for me that I don't understand much)

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is, I don't see any lost frames? I can advise not to use chatGPT if you don't understand the results.